# Simplificar submit Form Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo esta función y no se si se puede simplificar porque creo que es muy larga.

```
submitForm(){
  if(this.operatoId){ 
    this._oper.update(this.operatoId, this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
      },
      response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      });
  } else{
    this._oper.create(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
      },
      response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      });
  }
  this._location.back();
  this.toastr.success('Grup', '',{disableTimeOut:true,closeButton:true, positionClass:'toast-bottom-right'});
}

Gracias!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos detalles:

1. Se puede simplificar, ya que las funciones para manejar las respuestas son las mismas:

```js
submitForm(){
  const responseOK = 
    (val) =>  console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
  const responseKO = response => console.log("POST call in error", response);
  const finish = () => console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");

  if(this.operatoId){ 
    this._oper.update(this.operatoId, this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
      responseOK, responseKO,finish);
  } else{
    this._oper.create(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
      responseOK, responseKO,finish);
  }
  this._location.back();
  this.toastr.success('Grup', '',{disableTimeOut:true,closeButton:true, positionClass:'toast-bottom-right'});
}
```

2. Pero estudia bien lo que estás haciendo: el método HTTP POST se debería usar para crear y el método HTTP PUT para modificar si quieres tener una interfaz REST *estándar*